# Silverlight make listbox visible on button hover

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I cant find a (for sure) simple solution for a simple problem:
If have the following XAML code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Item">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter"></i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave"></i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <ListBox Visibility="Collapsed"></ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I would like the list box to show at MouseEnter and hide at MouseLeave. It is probably just a one-liner but i cant find it.
Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you are after:

```
<StackPanel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication;assembly=SilverlightApplication">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:BoolToUIElementVisibilityConverter x:Name="BoolToUIElementVisibilityConv"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Button Content="Item" x:Name="YourButton">
    </Button>
    <ListBox Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=YourButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToUIElementVisibilityConv}}">
        <ListBoxItem>a</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>b</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>c</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

with a class:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;

namespace SilverlightApplication
{
public class BoolToUIElementVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
        if ((bool)value == true)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return "Collapsed";
        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```